# How to set button breakpoint in html element?

Tags: html, css

This is my Code :

```
<a href="#" class="button nineteen">Download MEDEIL 1.0 - Free Edition <br />English Version</a>
```

if I set the above code, there are two buttons displayed because of the in-between `<br />` tag. Like,

1. Download MEDEIL 1.0 - Free Edition
2. English Version

But I want both in a single button.

what can i do ?

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VYvxy/499/)

Comment: i dont understand, what exactly you expect to happen, and what happens instead?

Comment: *"English version move to another box."* means?

Comment: I proposed an edit with a JSFiddle.

Comment: @Banana I think now it's clear.

Comment: following your update: `<br/>` means line break. if you don't want the line to break to a new one, dont add `<br/>`. they both are still the same button, just 2 lines instead of same line.

Comment: yep, I want two lines in the button text instead of a single line.

Comment: by "button" he means "link"

Comment: @ivinraj then your code does exactly that. those are not separate buttons, it is one link.

Comment: without br tag, it seems long.

Comment: @ivinraj then what **Actually** is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly then what you need to do is change the [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) property of your anchor tag to `inline-block` (or `block`, depending on your use case), like so:

```css
a{
    display:inline-block;
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
    padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Download MEDEIL 1.0 - Free Edition <br />English Version</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

add

```
display:block;
```

but you will need to manually set a width also.

Optionally, if you want the button to automatically set its own width:

```
text-align:center;
float:left;
```

don't forget to clear that nasty float.

http://jsfiddle.net/VYvxy/501/

Comment: don't know why people downvoted my question. Hi sharky, it works. But I love another one's answer. Upvote from my side.